# Dependent type automatic deduction

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming, type-deduction

is it possible to do something like:

```
template<class T, T type>
constexpr auto f(/* type used in some way... */) // -> decltype (etc. in case of C++11)
  {
  return std::integral_constant<T,t>{};
  }

constexpr auto z = f(3); // z is deduced as an integral_constant<int,3>;
```

It's for sure not possible using a runtime value, but 3 in this case is a compile time value. Maybe someone knows some trick I'm not aware of...

[edit]
  constexpr auto z2 = f<3>(); // This would be ok too

I just would like to avoid to repeat the type..

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `auto` template parameter in C++17:

```
template <auto T>
constexpr auto f()
{
    return std::integral_constant<decltype(T), T>{};
}
```

Usage:

```
f<3>(); // integral_constant<int, 3>
```

---

Alternatively, you need to wrap your value in a compile-time friendly way:

```
template <int X>
struct int_ 
{ 
    using type = int;
    static constexpr value = X; 
};

template <typename T>
constexpr auto f(T)
{
    return std::integral_constant<typename T::type, T::value>{};
}
```

Usage:

```
f(int_<3>{});
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I forgot to mention that it's a C++11 question. This is one of the reason one should go for C++17, because that code would be the ideal solution!  The second approach  unfortunately doesn't fit what I'm looking to achieve. I'd like to avoid the creation of structs like int_

Answer (score 2):

Since c++11 you can declare your own literals (I used here `std::index_sequence` and it's c++14 but you can easily find c++11 implementation of aforesaid):

```
#include <utility> // for std::index_sequence and std::size_t

constexpr std::size_t ipow(std::size_t base, int exp, std::size_t result = 1) {
  return exp < 1 ? result : ipow(base*base, exp/2, (exp % 2) ? result*base : result);
}

constexpr std::size_t vdot(std::index_sequence<>, std::index_sequence<>) {
    return 0;
}

template <std::size_t C, std::size_t... Cs, std::size_t I, std::size_t... Is>
constexpr std::size_t vdot(std::index_sequence<C, Cs...>, std::index_sequence<I, Is...>) {
    return C*ipow(10, I) + vdot(std::index_sequence<Cs...>{}, std::index_sequence<Is...>{});
}

template <char... Cs>
std::integral_constant<std::size_t, vdot(std::index_sequence<static_cast<std::size_t>(Cs - '0')...>{}, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Cs)>{})> operator ""_ic() {
    return {};
}

int main() {
   auto ic = 3_ic;
   static_cast<void>(ic);
}
```

[[live demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XVtVpsiSqekSn2nH)

Comment: I'll try to go deeper into your solution.. but I don't think is going to work for what I need: integral_constant< int(*)int, &myIntToIntFunction> for instance

Answer (score 1):

In C++11 and C++14 this is impossible as per

§14.8.2.5 [temp.deduct.type] 13 and 14

> A template type argument cannot be deduced from the type of a non-type
>   *template-argument*. [Example:

```
template<class T, T i> void f(double a[10][i]); 
int v[10][20]; 
f(v); // error: argument for template-parameter T cannot be deduced
```

> —end example ]

So you are forced to specify a type. e.g. `f<int, 3>(/*...*/)`

I give full credit to @Barry for teaching me this [in his answer to my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44265134/27678)

#### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6YxpVsYf6FjJ6oLM)